# Benchmarking Zlib Java vs. C

Tags: java, c, zlib, deflate

I'm trying to speed up my TIFF encoder initially written in Java by switching to C and have compiled [Zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) 1.2.8 with `Z_SOLO` defined and minimum set of C files: `adler32.c`, `crc32.c`, `deflate.c`, `trees.c` and `zutil.c`. Java is using [`java.util.zip.Deflater`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html).

I wrote a simple test program to assess performance in terms of compression level and speed and was puzzled by the fact that whatever level I require, compression does not kick in that much, considering the increasing amount of time required by higher levels. I was also amazed by Java actually performing better than a Visual Studio Release-compile (VC2010) in both compression *and* speed:

Java:

```
Level 1 : 8424865 => 6215200 (73,8%) in 247 cycles.
Level 2 : 8424865 => 6178098 (73,3%) in 254 cycles.
Level 3 : 8424865 => 6181716 (73,4%) in 269 cycles.
Level 4 : 8424865 => 6337236 (75,2%) in 334 cycles.
Level 5 : 8424865 => 6331902 (75,2%) in 376 cycles.
Level 6 : 8424865 => 6333914 (75,2%) in 395 cycles.
Level 7 : 8424865 => 6333350 (75,2%) in 400 cycles.
Level 8 : 8424865 => 6331986 (75,2%) in 437 cycles.
Level 9 : 8424865 => 6331598 (75,2%) in 533 cycles.
```

C:

```
Level 1 : 8424865 => 6215586 (73.8%) in 298 cycles.
Level 2 : 8424865 => 6195280 (73.5%) in 309 cycles.
Level 3 : 8424865 => 6182748 (73.4%) in 331 cycles.
Level 4 : 8424865 => 6337942 (75.2%) in 406 cycles.
Level 5 : 8424865 => 6339203 (75.2%) in 457 cycles.
Level 6 : 8424865 => 6337100 (75.2%) in 481 cycles.
Level 7 : 8424865 => 6336396 (75.2%) in 492 cycles.
Level 8 : 8424865 => 6334293 (75.2%) in 547 cycles.
Level 9 : 8424865 => 6333084 (75.2%) in 688 cycles.
```

Am I the only one witnessing such results? My guess is that the Zlib in the JVM is using assembly-type optimizations that I'm not including in my C project, or I am missing an obvious configuration step when compiling Zlib (or Visual Studio compiler sucks).

Here are both snippets:

Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    byte[] pix = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("MY_MOSTLY_UNCOMPRESSED.TIFF"));
    int szin = pix.length;
    byte[] buf = new byte[szin*101/100];
    int szout;
    long t0, t1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Deflater deflater = new Deflater(i);
        deflater.setInput(pix);
        szout = deflater.deflate(buf);
        deflater.finish();
        t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(String.format("Level %d : %d => %d (%.1f%%) in %d cycles.", i, szin, szout, 100.0f*szout/szin, t1 - t0));
    }
}
```

C:

```
#include <time.h>
#define SZIN 9000000
#define SZOUT 10000000
void main(void)
{
    static unsigned char buf[SZIN];
    static unsigned char out[SZOUT];
    clock_t t0, t1;
    int i, ret;
    uLongf sz, szin;
    FILE* f = fopen("MY_MOSTLY_UNCOMPRESSED.TIFF", "rb");
    szin = fread(buf, 1, SZIN, f);
    fclose(f);

    for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        sz = SZOUT;
        t0 = clock();
        compress2(out, &sz, buf, szin, i); // I rewrote compress2, as it's not available when Z_SOLO is defined
        t1 = clock();
        printf("Level %d : %d => %d (%.1f%%) in %ld cycles.\n", i, szin, sz, 100.0f*sz/szin, t1 - t0);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

After @MarkAdler's remarks, I tried different compressing strategies through `deflateInit2()` (namely `Z_FILTERED` and `Z_HUFFMAN_ONLY`):

`Z_FILTERED`:

```
Level 1 : 8424865 => 6215586 (73.8%) in 299 cycles.
Level 2 : 8424865 => 6195280 (73.5%) in 310 cycles.
Level 3 : 8424865 => 6182748 (73.4%) in 330 cycles.
Level 4 : 8424865 => 6623409 (78.6%) in 471 cycles.
Level 5 : 8424865 => 6604616 (78.4%) in 501 cycles.
Level 6 : 8424865 => 6595698 (78.3%) in 528 cycles.
Level 7 : 8424865 => 6594845 (78.3%) in 536 cycles.
Level 8 : 8424865 => 6592863 (78.3%) in 595 cycles.
Level 9 : 8424865 => 6591118 (78.2%) in 741 cycles.
```

`Z_HUFFMAN_ONLY`:

```
Level 1 : 8424865 => 6803043 (80.7%) in 111 cycles.
Level 2 : 8424865 => 6803043 (80.7%) in 108 cycles.
Level 3 : 8424865 => 6803043 (80.7%) in 106 cycles.
Level 4 : 8424865 => 6803043 (80.7%) in 106 cycles.
Level 5 : 8424865 => 6803043 (80.7%) in 107 cycles.
Level 6 : 8424865 => 6803043 (80.7%) in 106 cycles.
Level 7 : 8424865 => 6803043 (80.7%) in 107 cycles.
Level 8 : 8424865 => 6803043 (80.7%) in 108 cycles.
Level 9 : 8424865 => 6803043 (80.7%) in 107 cycles.
```

As expected per his comment, `Z_HUFFMAN_ONLY` does not change compression but performs *a lot* faster. With my data, `Z_FILTERED` was not faster and a little worse compression than the `Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY`.

Comment: I am surprised that level `3` is the smallest.  Are you sure there is not something odd about your data?

Comment: @PeterLawrey it's a "standard" TIFF file size 2800x2900, containing 2 pages, the first one being uncompressed, the second one being deflate-compressed. I could understand it as "compressing compressed data inflates them". I could try compressing the already-compressed data though, to see what's happening (if I have some time this week-end).

Comment: In the Java program, be aware that `fis.read(pix)` may not read the entire file, in which case the remainder of `pix` would be zeroes.  I suggest replacing the use of FileInputStream with `pix = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("MY_MOSTLY_UNCOMPRESSED.TIFF"))`.

Comment: The amount of compression you get depends on the data.  Most image files are already compressed to a significant degree, so you're not likely to see much additional compression.

Comment: @VGR thanks for the tip. In my quick'n'dirty test I made sure the buffer was large enough and it seems it read all bytes (same number as in C).

Comment: @HotLicks, indeed. But I was expecting to see increasingly better compression with increasing `level`, not see the "max-I-can-get" right away without much improvement after (as @PeterLawrey noticed, it surprisingly goes down from 0 to 3, then up at 4 and little down from then on).

Comment: Not surprising.  Each "level" is a different algorithm, and some work better on the given data (or in this case, more likely have less overhead) than others.

Comment: @Matthieu have you tried making the `unsigned char's` unsigned `ints`? Everytime it's being loaded in it has to convert it to an `int` either way. That could give you a speed up.

Comment: @progenhard Zlib expects an `unsigned char*` pointer (`Bytef*` in Zlib), and considering the size (and number) of my images, the 4x increase in memory is not worth the Zlib hacking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compression amounts and deltas are not surprising for uncompressed image data with essentially no matching strings.  The portion of the data that is compressed is not being compressed further -- it is being expanded slightly by some constant amount, so the variation is all on the uncompressed portion.

There is a change in algorithm between level 3 and 4, where level 3 goes for the first match it finds.  When there are hardly no matching strings, that will tend to minimize the overhead of sending string matches, hence the better compression.  You might do better still if string matching were turned off completely using `FILTERED` or `HUFFMAN_ONLY`.  `HUFFMAN_ONLY` also has the advantage of not even looking for matching strings, speeding up the compression significantly.

As for the speed difference, I can only guess that different compilers or different compiler optimizations were used.

Comment: is that HUFMAN_ONLY settable in java, too?

Comment: `HUFFMAN_ONLY` is in fact the Java option for `setStrategy`.  In zlib it's called `Z_HUFFMAN`.

Comment: Thank you, that explains why. If I find some time I'll try with FILTERED and HUFFMAN_ONLY and post the results.

Comment: I updated my post with the results I got with `Z_FILTERED` and `Z_HUFFMAN_ONLY`. I like that `Z_HUFFMAN_ONLY` strategy can still be decoded by JAI (the TIFF reader I'm using), though it gives me no compression at all on a test ramp image (0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 254, 255, 0, ...), it still give 80% compression on real-life example. Thank you for your hard work in developing that!